# Place of birth typo in ds 2019

Tags: usa, j1-visas

My ds 2019 form has a typo stating my place of birth as Raidur but actually in my passport it is correct i.e Raipur. I have a visa appointment in a couple of days. What should I do? I have contacted the university but it's weekend there.

Comment: My ds-160 form is perfectly alright.

Comment: Nothing to worry about.

Comment: What should I do then? Go to the visa interview or apply a new one and reschedule the interview?